# Enable qiskit backends in google colab

Tags: qiskit, programming, simulation

I am trying to enable backends by using qiskit.IBMQ.backends() methods in google colab. but it is showing error. How to enable this? AL time this backend showing an error. i have tried by using some other methods but still the same issue. very confused regarding this.
tried using provider(). but same prblem.plz help.

[image]

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: 'IBMQFactory' object has no attribute 'backend'

Comment: The above one is the error showing..

Answer (score 1):

`backends()` is a method in [`AccountProvider`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.AccountProvider.html) class not in `qiskit.IBMQ`.
So, at first you need to get a provider and then use it to get the backends:

```
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub = 'ibm-q')
provider.backends()
```

You can find more details [here](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/manage/account/ibmq).

Comment: Ok.. i will read it.. thank you.